# getting popular or relevant words from input for use as tags

Tags: php, tagging, folksonomy

We all know how tagging on SO works. We make a post, tag it and it helps in searches and is used in folksonomy.

this is what I want to do. Instead of forcing people to tag posts, I can somehow fetch relevant words from the post to use as tags.

Apart from say, fetching repeating words, is there a method of getting words of relevance from a post? Maybe a language parser which can detect words of import?

Please give me your own ideas. It doesn't have to be along the lines I am thinking. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a table that is a look-up for your keywords.  Then search the text entries against your list for hits.

Since you presumably want your tags generated on-the-fly, you would need a large list of words.  Those are easy to find (search on "word list").  Then you can delete words of little interest, or even rank them according to relevance.